# Very slow {align*} typesetting

Tags: amsmath, accessibility

I am typesetting some tutorial sheet answers for a class I am teaching.  I have an `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` block which contains 6 or 7 of lines like:

```
\text{ZG:} \quad &
  E^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} =
   \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 156 \\ 167 \end{pmatrix} \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix} \mod 26   \\
```

The pages which have these blocks on take *forever* to typeset on my otherwise fast desktop computer: multiple seconds a page.  (Using `pdflatex` with a recent version on `MikTeX`.)  In many years of using LaTeX I don't think I've even had a document be so slow, per page.

(The pages also contain a couple of small figures which I ask to be typeset with the `[h]` option.  But with these commented out, the same behaviour persists.  It does seem to be the `{align*}` block.)

I am interested in what is "happening under the hood" to slow LaTeX down so much.

**Update:**  Thanks to people asking me to build a "minimal test case", I indeed quite easily found the problem: the `axessibility` package.  I'm using this because of new rules in the UK about making documents accessible (for teaching purposes...)  A test document with just the alignment and the `axessibility` package is very slow, without the `axessibility` package, it's normal speed.

Here's a test case:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{axessibility}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{ZG:} \quad &
  E^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ 6\end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 156 \\ 167 \end{pmatrix} \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 11 \end{pmatrix} \mod 26   \\
\text{LX:} \quad &
  E^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ 23 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ 23 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 89 \\ 216 \end{pmatrix} \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix} 11 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix} \mod 26   \\
\text{TI:} \quad &
   E^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 19 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 19 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 122 \\ 151 \end{pmatrix} \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix} 18 \\ 21 \end{pmatrix} \mod 26   \\
\text{NA:} \quad &
  E^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 13 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 13 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 78 \\ 65 \end{pmatrix} \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 13 \end{pmatrix} \mod 26   \\
\text{BC:} \quad &
  E^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 19 \end{pmatrix} \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 19 \end{pmatrix} \mod 26   \\
\text{ZE:} \quad &
  E^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 1 \\ 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 25 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} 154 \\ 153 \end{pmatrix} \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix} 24 \\ 23 \end{pmatrix} \mod 26   \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please show a test document we can not debug a fragment. It is very unlikely that setting a single alignment takes a measurable amount of time on a current machine. You'd have to set a few hundred or few thousand to get realistic timings, so something else must be happening

Comment: Very happy to do that: is there a standard way to attach a test case?  If I can get a very short test case working, I'll just paste it in.  But what if it ends up being long?

Comment: Thanks for the revised example, yes it's slower (but doing a lot more:-) The latex team is working towards having accessibility features built in but we'll have to see what effect it has on speed. Nothing comes for free though. See https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2020-tagged-pdf-feasibility.pdf

Comment: I wouldn't call it *much* slower, it takes the double time one my machine, but creating all the pdf objects for the structure tree needs some time. The easiest is to comment the package while writing. But be aware that you will *not* produce an accessible document with this. They are loading tagpdf but use them only for math, so the rest of the document has no structure. Be also aware that tagpdf is an highly  *experimental* package not meant for production and bound to change. Read its documentation before using it.